# Create variable interactions as a routine

Tags: r, regression, interaction, lasso-regression

From my dataset `df` variable size is numeric (can be converted to a numeric where **small = 1, medium = 2, large = 3**).

```
id <- c('1','2','3','4', '5')
size <- c('small', 'large', 'small', 'small', 'medium')
dest1 <- c('1', '0', '1', '0', '1')
dest2 <- c('0', '1', '1', '0', '1')
via1 <- c('1', '1', '0', '0', '0')
via2 <- c('1', '0', '1', '0', '1')
value <- c('4', '561', '310', '106', '8')

df <- data.frame(id, size, dest1, dest2, via1, via2, value)
```

I want to interact in a systematic way, the variable `size` with variables starting with `dest` and `via` separately, (in my original dataset I have hundreds of variables starting with these words).  I tried it manually (size x dummy) but takes a lot of time to go like this for all possible interactions.

So finally the new database have to look like `df1`. What is your proposal to get it?

```
size_dest1 <- c('1', '0', '1', '1', '2')
size_dest2 <- c('0', '3', '1', '0', '2')
size_via1 <- c('1', '3', '0', '0', '0')
size_via2 <- c('1', '0', '1', '0', '2')
df1 <- data.frame(id, size, dest1, dest2, via1, via2, value, size_dest1, size_dest2, size_via1, size_via2)
```

Any clue?

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including any solutions you've attempted and the expected output, and update your question. As currently written it's too unfocused for people to answer.

Comment: I have included the solution I tried it. Moreover I have included a reproducible example of my problem and how will look the expected outcome. Question is also edited despite the fact that from the first comment I have received it seems my question is focused and clear for the reader. @LenGreski

Answer (score 2):

An option is to reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, recode the values in 'size', do the multiplication on the 'size', 'via' columns, reshape back to 'wide' format and join with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% 
      # // columns were all character.  So, changed the type
      type.convert(as.is = TRUE)


df %>% 
    # // reshape to long format
    pivot_longer(cols = dest1:via2, names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
           names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
    # // recode the size column
    mutate(size = setNames(1:3, c('small', 'medium', 'large'))[size],  
       # // loop over the 'dest', 'via' columns, multiply with size 
       across(c(dest, via), ~ . * size, .names = "size_{.col}")) %>% 
   # // remove the columns not needed
   select(-size, -dest, -via) %>%
   # // reshape to wide format
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(size_dest, size_via)) %>%
   # // join with the original dataset
   right_join(df) %>%
   # // reorder the columns in select
   select(names(df), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#     id size   dest1 dest2  via1  via2 size_dest_1 size_dest_2 size_via_1 size_via_2
#  <int> <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>       <int>       <int>      <int>      <int>
#1     1 small      1     0     1     1           1           0          1          1
#2     2 large      0     1     1     0           0           3          3          0
#3     3 small      1     1     0     1           1           1          0          1
#4     4 small      0     0     0     0           0           0          0          0
#5     5 medium     1     1     0     1           2           2          0          2
```

Comment: All goes good until:     "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `size_dest` doesn't exist." that appear in the line "# // reshape to wide format
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(size_dest, size_via)) %>%". Any idea?

Comment: @vog Not sure about that error.  I used the same data from the input.   Do you have a different version of `tidyr`